# should both scores of 2 time points be of same scale in mixed ANOVA

Tags: anova, assumptions, normality-assumption, mixed-model

I am running mixed ANOVA as repeated measurement analysis for cognitive score at 2 time points for 2 groups (blood pressure low vs. High). The the score at time 1 was normally distributed and at time 2 was not normally distributed so I QURT transformed.

Can I still use mixed ANOVA? or both scores should be of same scale/ units? if both should be same, what should i do, transform time 1 or use the original time 2?

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot transfom one variable but not the other.** This simply doesn't make any sense, they need to be on the same scale (otherwise you trivially get a main effect of time).

Usually, people are overcutious with the normality assumption disregarding several important aspects:

- Normality testing is potentially "[essentially useless](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/442)". So shouldn't be used for your different time points.
- The assumption of normality does not concern the raw data, but the residuals, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6350/442) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/60410/442).

I would probably go with the raw values but plot those and the residuals and only consider alternatives if the deviations are dramatic.