# Non-Normal data in multiple linear regression

Tags: multiple-regression, references, normality-assumption

My study involve 73 subject.
I want to carry out a multiple linear regression in order to form a predicting formula. However my dependent variable is not normally distributed according to a normality test. It is close to normal distirubtion in the p-value of normality test and it looks like normal distributed data in histograms.

In this case should I continue using multiple linear regression or Should I transform the variable/using non-parametric regression method?

If I can continue using multiple linear regression, is there any statistical journal that I can cite for explaining why I can do that? Do you have some key words that I can google for?

Comment: Which normality test are you using?

Comment: First recognize that it's in no way a requirement of linear regression that the dependent variable should follow a normal distribution - see e.g. [What if residuals are normally distributed, but y is not?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12262/17230) or [Normality of dependent variable = normality of residuals?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/60410/17230).

Comment: Tp Ferdi: Shapiro–Wilk test

Comment: To Scortchi: So it is ok to run the linear regression am I right? Thanks you!

Comment: Yes - then examine the residuals to check assumptions.